# Why does native resolution capture with picamera raise 'Incorrect Buffer Length' for Arducam 8MP with IMX219 sensor?

Tags: camera, python-3, picamera

I am trying to `capture()` full resolution images using `picamera.array` but it fails raising a `PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 3280x2464`.

`camera.MAX_RESOLUTION` gives `PiResolution(width=3280, height=2464)`. If I subtract 16 and 32 from width and height respectively, I get a valid output and the image displays.

This is the python3 code I am using:

```
import picamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
import matplotlib.pyplot as pat

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:

    with picamera.array.PiRGBArray(camera) as output:
        camera.resolution = (
            camera.MAX_RESOLUTION.width-16
            ,camera.MAX_RESOLUTION.height-32)
        #camera.resolution = (3280,2464)
        camera.capture(output, 'rgb')
        plt.imshow(output.array)
```

Not being able to use those pixels is not dramatic but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

If anyone cares about the [full error stack](https://github.com/mmarras/ArduCam/blob/master/Traceback_ArduCam_FullRes) I get when I request the native resolution, I linked it on GitHub.

Comment: Btw. subtracting integers bigger than 16 or 32 also works.